# Solid State Hard Drive for Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a Inspiron 1525. I would like to replace the existing hard drive with a solid state hard drive. What size do I need (in terms of inches not gigabytes.) I'm thinking something around 80-100GB would be sufficient for me. I will be installing it myself.

Comment: How can we possibly know what size you would need? how much money is not alot? Based on: "I don't need a lot of space and wouldn't like to spend a lot of money." I would say the cheapest one you can find??? What do you want us to tell you the above criteria is personal and nebulous....

Comment: @Kyle - He maybe means 'dimensions' rather than 'storage capacity'?  Still, please clarify.  This is a terrible question as-is, way too vague.

Comment: @shinrai Ah, Didn't even think about that... The part about not needing a lot of space made me instantly equate size with capacity. you need a 2.5 inch or 1.8 inch that you know for certain has a 2.5 bracket.

Comment: Please add hdd size (dimensions & storage). Add your budget (ie: less than $200). Will you be installing it?

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: Much better! :)

Comment: most laptops use 2.5" drives

Comment: @codedude Why do you ask in terms of inches and then say, "you're thinking about 80-100GB"? Also see: [What are the differences between 2.5“ and 3.5” hard disks?](http://superuser.com/questions/281613/what-are-the-differences-between-2-5-and-3-5-hard-disks/281616#281616).

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing laptop hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/196273/replacing-laptop-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the size for laptop drives are 2.5". The 3.5" drives are for desktops/servers/network storage typically.

Answer (score 0):

The best first stop for solid state is the [SSD decoder as perper.com](http://www.pcper.com/ssd-decoder). It has a lot of information about size and speed.

For people who don't know anything about SSD's, Intel is the "standard" for SSD's. Most SSD's are designed to be installed in a laptop. Unless dell did something weird, it should be a 2.5" drive.

If you can enable [AHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) on your laptop, I would go for it. Not all laptops support this interface standard so make sure you have that feature before you buy. Also, make sure you are on windows 7 so you can get TRIM support.

Hope this helps