# Which HDD is compatible with my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hard drives are compatible with laptops?](https://superuser.com/questions/196273/what-hard-drives-are-compatible-with-laptops)

I use a laptop with an HDD on its death spin. I wanted to buy a 500GB HDD to replace my current 320GB. However I was told not to do so and rather buy the same model that came with the laptop.

Can you please tell me the criteria for compatibility apart from SATA/eSata interface?

Comment: As you can read in our FAQ, shopping recommendations are off topic. Your question is also a little localized to your current model – we can't have one question on which HDD is compatible with every laptop there might exist. Fact is: All typical laptops use 2.5" SATA disks these days. You can buy almost any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to buy the same model of HDD as you have, you can use any compatible (2,5" SATA) HDD. so look for a 2,5" SATA 3.0Gb/s 500GB disk

Comment: Do all laptops use 2.5" drives?

Comment: No, but 99% of them do. It if you had one which did not then you would probably be aware of that (or for nothing else as due to the hefty price tag and a lot of marketing stating 'ULTRA MEGA SUPER MEGA small maximum weight reduction' etc etc. :)

Comment: I don't know of any current laptop model that has 3,5" disk, so I would have to say yes, And you provided your current model of disk which is 2,5" SATA 3.0GB/s http://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Momentus-ST9320423AS-Bare-Frustration-Free-Packaging/dp/B0027P9BO2

Comment: Guys which would you recommend?

Comment: @FasihKhatib - We don't do product suggestions on Stack Exchange websites. I have provided you two HDDs that are EXACTLY the same HDD just larger.  I likely shouldn't even have done that to promote the concept of good valid questions on this website.

Comment: my bad there~!!!

Comment: @FasihKhatib - I went ahead an answered it because your question other then being not on topic for this website was well written.  As I pointed out the two HDDs I suggested are exactly the same except for their size.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please tell me which other HDDs are compatible with my laptop
>   or the criteria for compatibility apart from SATA/eSata interface?

Any SATA 2.5" HDD will be compatibile with your laptop.

[Seagate Momentus 7200 750 GB 7200RPM SATA 3Gb/s 16 MB Cache 2.5 Inch Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive ST9750420AS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MME0N0)

[Seagate Momentus 7200 500 GB SATA 3Gb/s NCQ 16MB Cache 2.5 Inch Internal Notebook Hard Drive ST9500423AS - Bare Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006KYYBMI)

Both of these HDDs are the same model as your previous HDD just larger.

Comment: 500GB for $77 and 750GB for $79. Black magic sorcery? :p

Comment: @FasihKhatib - Both of those models are several generations old.